# Send amp-form data to mailchimp with Nextjs

Tags: next.js, mailchimp, amp-html

I have a a standard amp form, with an email input, and a sumbit input, and a mailchimp endpoint.

```html
<form
  method="post"
  action-xhr={`https://${DATACENTER}.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/lists/${LIST_ID}/members`}
  target="_top"
>
  <fieldset>
    <input
      type="email"
      name="email"
      placeholder="Enter your email"
      required
      className="email-input"
    />
    <input
      type="submit"
      value="Sign Up"
      className="sign-input"
    />
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

now the problem is, i need to configure headers,to provide an Authorization API key, and to setup cors.

AMP requires to use xhr to send data. and i have no idea on how to do that inside nextjs, or a serverless function for that matter.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I tried creating an endpoint /api/subscribe, and that endpoint will hold the xhr logic of sending to mailchimp. But again, there is no way of sending data(email in this case), to that endpoint, unless there is a body request, which xhr doesn't appear to support.

Comment: if you show your code, i can share it with someone who has done this (using slack, not mailchimp, but the approach is the same). Without code it's **very** difficult to offer suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try this solution - https://www.miguoliang.com/how-to-build-a-mailchimp-embed-form-in-amp-pages.html

You'll have to make an API using mailchimp's python library and provide the credentials and use that API to post data from the form.